# Why is my solution to the 3n+1 puzzle being rejected?

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, memoization

I am trying to solve algorithmic problems on the UVa online judge but I am stuck on the [3n+1 problem](https://uva.onlinejudge.org/index.php?option=com_onlinejudge&Itemid=8&page=show_problem&problem=36). I see the right output every time, but the judge says it is a wrong answer. Why?

Also, how can I optimize this code so that it does not take a long time for 1000000?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    int a;


 int b;
    int cyclelength(int i);
     while (scanf("%d %d\n",&a,&b)==2){

    int max = 0;

   if (b < a){
        for (int i = b; i < a; i++){
        if (cyclelength(i) > max)
            max = cyclelength(i);
             }
   }

   else    
   {
        for (int i = a; i < b; i++){
             if (cyclelength(i) > max)
                  max = cyclelength(i);
         }
   }


    cout << a << " " << b << " " << max << endl;

    }
}

int cyclelength(int i){
    if(i==1)
        return 1;


    if(!(i%2))
         return cyclelength(i/2)+1;
     else
        return cyclelength(3*i+1)+1;
     }
```

Comment: The first question of `3n+1`? Given how much information that line carries, I could just say that you try to `Q* approach with memoization`. Wait a sec, that sounds like rubbish. So does `3n + 1` to me. Please elaborate on your question.

Comment: If this code produces the right output, then there's nothing wrong with this code. If you aren't sure how to test your code, ask us about that. We don't care what the online judge says, and *don't* point us to the online problem statement.

Comment: We can see that you call `cyclelength` a lot of times. It seems like, for example, `cyclelength(42)` would always return the same value. Perhaps you can somehow remember some of the results, and reduce the number of calls.

Comment: @therainmaker memoization sounds like a good idea though ;)

Comment: @NiklasB. Haha. To be honest, I felt really frustrated that the person assumed we'd know the `3n+1` problem. Out of curiosity, is it something common, which I should've known?

Comment: @therainmaker Well it's not common to  call it "3n+1 problem", but I guess this term is sometimes used to refer to the problem of computing [Collatz chain lengths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture)

Comment: Sorry everyone. The question was

Start with an integer n. If n is even, divide by 2. If n is odd, multiply by 3 and add 1. Repeat this process with the new value of n, terminating when n = 1. For example, the following sequence of numbers will be generated for n = 22:

22 11 34 17 52 26 13 40 20 10 5 16 8 4 2 1

It means the cyclelength of 22 is the total number it passes through to reach upto 1, i.e 16. 

For memoization, as a n00b programmer, I tried creating a list which was even more frustating. lol. I will try again though. Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your submission is incorrect because you aren't iterating over the range from `a` to `b`, inclusive.

The problem statement reads:

> For each pair of input integers *i* and *j* you should output *i*, *j*, and the maximum cycle length for integers between and including *i* and *j*.

Your code loops over

```
for (int i = b; i < a; i++)
```

and

```
for (int i = a; i < b; i++)
```

thus omitting `a` in the former case and `b` in the latter.

You should change the loops to

```
for (int i = b; i <= a; i++)
```

and

```
for (int i = a; i <= b; i++)
```

You can speed up your code somewhat by [memoizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) the results of `cyclelength`. This lets you look up previously computed values instead of spending time on computing them again.

Here is a memoized version of `cyclelength`:

```
#include <map>
using namespace std;

map<long long, int> memo;

int cyclelength(long long i) {
  if (i == 1) {
    return 1;
  } 

  if (memo.count(i) == 1) {
    return memo[i];
  }

  if (i%2 == 0) { 
    return memo[i] = 1 + cyclelength(i/2);
  } else { 
    return memo[i] = 1 + cyclelength(3*i + 1);
  } 
}
```

An `unordered_map` would be faster, but the UVA judge returned a compilation error for `#include <unordered_map>`.

Note that my version of `cyclelength` takes a `long long` argument. That lets me calculate `cyclelength(999999)`, which eventually causes an integer overflow due to repeated 3n+1 operations if you limit yourself to 32-bit integer values. The problem statement promises that "no operation overflows a 32-bit integer" and you can get your submission accepted if you only use `int` values, but you have to use a larger integer type if you want to compute `cyclelength` for values in the range [1, 1000000).

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing out the stupid error in my loop. I will try that. Also, I tried using array for memoization which turned out to be worse, but this seems nice. Thanks alot :)